# How do you change a JavaFX Label's textFill with a KeyFrame?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

So I generally understand that a keyframe constructor takes in the node property and desired end value.

For example:

> > new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), new KeyValue(YourNode.layoutXProperty, 75));

However, Label.textFill does not exist, and getTextFill is a getter, not a member variable. Is there any way to get around this?

The code would work something like:

> new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), new KeyValue(YourNode.textFill, Color.GREEN));

Comment: [`label.textFillProperty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#textFillProperty)?

Comment: Re your last comment to a deleted question -- yes, the requirements *may* seem arbitrary, but please understand that the site has evolved and continues to evolve, including the requirements for questions. The link that you provided was to a question asked near when this site was just starting out, and the current rules did not apply. Again the rules *have* changed since then, but to help the poster, they are well described in the various links found in the [help] section. Also the rules and the fine tuning of these rules evolve and this is mainly discussed in the site's meta section which ....

Comment: ... I invite you to check out and contribute.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That totally makes sense. My interest in the discussion over these rules was too better my understanding of what is/isn't acceptable, as I'm becoming increasingly involved in personal projects, am learning a lot quickly, and would like to become a more active member of the community.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It is understandable that the rules evolve over time, I hadn't checked the date on that post originally. That link wasn't a gotcha btw, I had just found it when I had searched originally before asking my question, and the styling of that question is what made me feel like my question was of an appropriate level of depth and specificity.

Comment: I understand. And those of us who vote aren't perfect either, and try to judge questions on their merit, and not based on the questioner himself/herself. If you ever do decide to contest a question on the meta, do be aware of the [Meta Effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect) where asking a question on meta about a stackoverflow question brings additional attention to the question, possibly positive attention and possibly negative attention. Just a warning since usually this doesn't help the poster (but on occasion does). Much luck!

Comment: Again, I can't repeat this enough. I totally get why this community is so strict, and I recognize the benefits drawn from tight moderation. I appreciate how friendly and helpful you've been, and I'll try to take your advice in any future posts.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thank you for that advice. I wouldn't really look to dispute anyway, since I'm obviously a new member of the site, and it's safe to assume the veterans telling me I'm wrong is a sign I'm wrong. My only last question would be, do you think the question we are currently commenting on was better/acceptable? I know I've dragged out this conversation to an annoying extent, but seeing examples of good practices is always a good chance to learn about the site's etiquette, ya know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern for method naming for a JavaFX property `xxx` of type `T` is:

```
public Property<T> xxxProperty() // returns the property itself
public T getXxx() // returns the value of the property
public void setXxx(T x) // sets the value of the property
```

So, for example, for the `textFill` property which `Label` inherits from `Labeled`, there is a [`public ObjectProperty<Paint> textFillProperty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#textFillProperty) method, returning the actual property.

So all you need is

```
new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), new KeyValue(label.textFillProperty(), Color.GREEN))
```

SSCCE:

```
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class TextFillTransition extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label label = new Label("Transitioning the fill of a label");
        label.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 24pt ;");

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0), new KeyValue(label.textFillProperty(), Color.RED)),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), new KeyValue(label.textFillProperty(), Color.GREEN))
        );
        timeline.setAutoReverse(true);
        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();

        StackPane root = new StackPane(label);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(12));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Ahh, this is completely correct. Not sure why I was unable to find it originally, but that makes complete sense. Thank you!